# Linkage error when performing TestNG with expected exceptions and Powermock

Tags: java, testng, powermock, powermockito, linkageerror

I am working on a Maven project, and I am trying to perform a TestNG unit test with the following structure:

```
import org.testng.*;

@PrepareForTest(GeneralDAO.class)
@PowerMockIgnore({"javax.management.*"})
public class TestClass extends PowerMockTestCase {

    @Test(expectedExceptions = BusinessException.class) // custom exception from another project
    public void testFailToGetBusiness() {

        // method that shoud throw a BusinessException

    }
}
```

But when I am running the test, I find out the following exception:

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "com.company.exception.BusinessException.<init>(Ljava/lang/Exception;Lcom/company/exception/EExceptionCodes;)V"
the class loader (instance of org/powermock/core/classloader/MockClassLoader)
of the current class, com/company/core/BusinessHandler, 
and the class loader (instance of sun/misc/Launcher$AppClassLoader) for the method's defining class, com/company/exception/BusinessException, 
have different Class objects for the type com/company/exception/EExceptionCodes used in the signature
```

As far as I understand, powermock loads the Object with MockClassLoader for the testing environment, and Sun uses his AppClassLoader to load the same Object. As the classloaders are different, in runtime the objects also are (beyond they have the same name), and that implies a LinkageError.

Anyway, I have tried several ways to avoid that, for example by removing the expectedExceptions tag and adding a try and catch clause, but with no success.

How could I set an unique class loader for that Exception? Is that the correct approach to solve it? Or should I try with something else? Could be something wrong with my Maven configuration? Any ideas or comments are welcome :)

Comment: Which testng version do you use? Did you try the latest?

Comment: Which powermock version do you use? 1.6.3 was released few days ago and powermock has some classpath issues. ie: https://github.com/jayway/powermock/issues/579

Comment: Hi, I am using TestNG 6.9.6 with powermock 1.6.3. As far as I know they are the latests ones.

Comment: @juherr Thanks for the reference. I found quite interesting this part of a comment: "The problem really is that the MockClassLoader does not provide a reference to the mock class it loaded.". Maybe here is the root of the problem, but at the moment I am not sure if I could find a workaround, or even if a workaround is the best solution for this.

Comment: As a workaround you can also prepare the exception class (annotate it with @PrepareForTest) to make MockClassLoader loads the exception class, also you need to use try and catch instead of expectedExceptions.

Answer (score 0):

Removing from the expected exception and refactoring to [assertThrows](https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.testng/testng/latest/org/testng/Assert.html#assertThrows(java.lang.Class,org.testng.Assert.ThrowingRunnable)) syntax worked for me. You would need to do it for all tests which have the expected exception as your conflicting class. It prevents the powermock class loader to load the class and fixes the linkage error.